# Wildcard SSL certificates Azure websites. Compatible?

Tags: azure, ssl

I am looking to install a wildcard SSL certificate onto azure, however I do not want to spend the money only to find that it does not work. As they seem to be 100s of pounds.

I need to have a SSL certificate which covers the *.domainame.com

There seems to not be much documentation on this issue, however I came across a forum post where someone was having a problem with it.

[Troubleshooting wildcard ssl certificate issue in azure](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/713d3512-650a-4cf4-975e-4a367c661a88/troubleshooting-wildcard-ssl-certificate-issue-in-azure)

Has anyone successfully installed a wildcard certificate onto azure?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a wild card SSL in Azure.  I had to add entries for every domain I wanted to use with it under SSL Bindings.  So, I created one entry for domain.com and attached the wildcard SSL cert and then another for www.domain.com and attached the same wild card SSL cert.  That seemed to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can definitely use one SSL certificate in this scenario. This is a great article on setting it up : http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/enable-ssl/

We do this for all of our development environments in Azure, as we have one SSL certificate that covers 34 sites.

When deploying, just make sure you have a reference to it in your ServiceConfiguration.csfg :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceConfiguration serviceName="Company.One.Azure" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceConfiguration" osFamily="3" osVersion="*" schemaVersion="2013-03.2.0">
<Role name="Company.One.Web">
<Instances count="1" />
<ConfigurationSettings>     
</ConfigurationSettings>
<Certificates>
  <Certificate name="SslCertificate" thumbprint="{YourThumbPrintHere}" thumbprintAlgorithm="sha1" />
</Certificates>
```

Comment: He's asking about Azure Websites, not Cloud Services

Comment: @Ignorek Did you click on the link he referenced? Probably not. The thread pertains to SSL certificates for web roles, which are part of cloud services.

Comment: I did click on the link.  Webroles are cloud services.  He's asking about Azure *Websites*

Comment: yup I am asking about Azure Websites. Can anyone confirm if this is possible. Or know how I can talk to the azure team directly?

Comment: So if you're still in development, how can you get the thumbprint - second to last line in the config file section shown above?

Comment: @KarlZ You can double click the .CER file and then go to Details tab and view\copy the Thumbprint. You can view\copy from Certificates tab of the Cloud Service. If .CER is installed locally you can also have VS create this entire entry for you from the WebRole > Properties > Certificate page.

Answer (score 0):

Based on these two links I would say that **Azure Websites** are compatible with wildcard ssl certificates.

Your site need to be in `Standard Mode` though.

[Windows Azure Custom domain name documentation](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-custom-domain-name/?fb=nl-nl%5d)

[Windows Azure Enable HTTPS for a Windows Azure web site](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure-ssl-certificate/?fb=nl-nl)

Comment: By "Standard", do you mean a Standard App Service plan? Where do you see this?

Comment: Yes, I mean the standard app service plan.